# Debugging when deserializing a Json file with JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json.net

Is there a way to "debug a Json file" at deserialisation using JsonConvert?
It would be very useful if the line (or group of lines) of the Json file being processed could be printed as a debug option.
Otherwise, when the deserialisation of a Json file into an object fails, it can be very difficult to figure out what is wrong with that file.

Comment: Check https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationTracing.htm

Comment: I will check it out, thanks

Comment: @Dominik, ok I see, but that only allows you to spit out the entire log in one go. Is there no way to print as you go (ie. as you deserialise, not when it is already all done)?

Comment: Well I they write into this `TraceWriter` as they go. Since it's an interface you can implement it and write into console every time they trace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement a custom `TraceWriter` that logs to console as deserialization goes on, like this. Of course you could also wrap it into a log4net log entry or just do whatever you like.:

```
public class ConsoleTraceWriter : ITraceWriter
{    
    public TraceLevel LevelFilter
    {
        // trace all messages (Verbose and above)
        get { return TraceLevel.Verbose; }
    }

    public void Trace(TraceLevel level, string message, Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex != null) {
            Console.WriteLine(level.ToString() + ": " + message + " Ex: " + ex.Message);
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine(level.ToString() + ": " + message);
        }
    }
}
```

And set it at deserialization

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJson, new JsonSerializerSettings { TraceWriter = new ConsoleTraceWriter() });
```